# Authorize an user from my angular application to access Azure DevOps REST API services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-ad-msal, azure-devops-rest-api, microsoft-identity-platform

I am trying to use Microsoft Identity Platform to authorize users to access Azure DevOps REST APIs in my Angular SPA, similar to how it is done for Graph API authorization. Do I use Azure Portal and register my app and include the Azure DevOps API with user_impersonation scope?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use Microsoft Identity Platform to access Azure DevOps REST APIs.

For angular application that want access to resources like Azure DevOps REST API's, you can click [Microsoft Authentication Library for JavaScript (MSAL.js)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js#microsoft-authentication-library-for-javascript-msaljs) for detailed information.

And [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/JavascriptWebAppSample) is a code sample.

Comment: Thank you and appreciate your response. I will try to explore that solution. I had switched projects so did not get chance to explore further.